# Redirect from one controller action to another including a http header

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, http-headers, .net-4.6.2

I am working with a .net framework 4.6.2, MVC project where I want to call a controller action, do some processing and once complete, redirect to another controller action, passing to it a http header with a get request.

To achieve this, to pass a http header, do I need to return back to the browser the initial controller action and get the browser to perform the subsequent redirect client side, including the http header in it? From my research I can find a way for one controller action call another controller action, via a GET, including a header with it.

Comment: You should use [`RedirectToAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction) which returns a HTTP 302 response.

Comment: Can a http header be added as part of that redirect?

Comment: It automatically adds a Location header pointing at the endpoint specified in your call to `RedirectToAction`.